# unit for theta coming from hector mapping or laser scan matcher

Tags: ros, navigation, mapping, uav, hector-mapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi im using hector mapping on my quardotor and have problems with the theta coming out of /poseupdate. When i yaw the quad 90 degrees i get a value of 0.63 - 0.7 . If i consider this to be in radians and convert it, the value in degrees is about 36 - 40 degrees. I've also tried with laser scan matcher with the same result.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32900/unit-for-theta-coming-from-hector-mapping-or-laser-scan-matcher/) by [vivek](https://answers.ros.org/users/1350/vivek/) on ROS Answers with karma: 53 on 2012-04-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That indeed sounds a bit weird. the pose published on the /poseupdate topic is the pose relative to the /map frame (by default). Did you consider that the orientation is given as a quaternion and that you can´t just look at the "z" component of it to retrieve to yaw angle in rad?

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2012-04-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [vivek](https://answers.ros.org/users/1350/vivek/) on 2012-04-30**:
yes i got that and when i use it as a quaternion im getting the values right. thanks for the reply